# Simplifying a trig expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions

How can I get Mathematica to simplify the following expression?

```
Pi-ArcCos[-1/Sqrt[3]]
```

I'd like the answer to be ArcCos[1/Sqrt[3]], which seems manifestly "simpler" to me. If I use Simplify, it leaves it as it is. A related question is: howcome

```
Pi-ArcCos[-1/Sqrt[3]]==ArcCos[1/Sqrt[3]]
```

does not return True or False, but rather returns back the same expression?

Comment: `FullSimplify[Pi - ArcCos[-1/Sqrt[3]] - ArcCos[1/Sqrt[3]]]` performs `0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

expr = Pi - ArcCos[-1/Sqrt[3]];
```

The simplification is available in [`MathematicalFunctionData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MathematicalFunctionData.html)

```
argSimp = (MathematicalFunctionData["ArcCos", 
       "ArgumentSimplifications"][[1]][z] // Activate) /. Equal :> Rule

(* ArcCos[-z] -> π - ArcCos[z] *)

expr /. (argSimp /. z :> 1/Sqrt[3])

(* ArcCos[1/Sqrt[3]] *)
```

**EDIT:** Use [`ComplexExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html) to test the equality

```
Pi - ArcCos[-1/Sqrt[3]] == ArcCos[1/Sqrt[3]] // ComplexExpand

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 4):

I would claim that your expected form is not the simplest one. I would instead propose
$$
\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)
$$
and do the simplification as follows

```
e = Pi - ArcCos[-1/Sqrt[3]];
es = ArcTan[Tan[e]]
FullSimplify[e==es]
(* ArcTan[Sqrt[2]] *)
(* True *)
```